# EF datacontext in multiple projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I have 3 projects

1. DAL (data access layer) - console application with models, and my `DbContext` (called `WarehouseContext`)
2. BLL (business logic layer) - console application with DTO models and controllers
3. PL (presentation layer) - WPF application using MVVM pattern (I don't use Models part of MVVM tho.)

Where, and how, should I create, and initialize the `WarehouseContext` variable in order to use it across all 3 layers? I suppose I just should create it in the DAL Program class (I usually do it using DI in web apps, mb I should do this).

PS: I can't change the architecture, because it's a task.

Comment: From what you describe, the Context/entities would solely be referenced by the BLL which would return DTOs/Models for the PL to consume. The PL would have no knowledge of entities or the DbContext. The challenge for MVVM/WPF is avoiding situations where DbContexts are alive too long. They should exist only as long as needed to fetch data and/or persist data. Avoid the temptation to leave a DbContext open and interacting with entities from the time data is fetched to the time the user may or may not want to persist changes.